# Way to use User32/GDI32/Kernel32 in NaCl module

Tags: winapi, google-chrome-extension, user32, google-nativeclient, kernel32

I have ActiveX and NPAPI Plugin using Win32 API. I'd like to port that plugins to NaCl module.
But I can't find way to build with Win32 libs. Can I use User32/GDI32/Kernel32 APIs in NaCl?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, Native Client does not allow the use of OS-specific functions or libraries. The only way you can communicate with the OS is through the browser via the [Pepper Plugin API (PPAPI)](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/peppercpp/files).

[Update] Another solution is to use [Native Messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging). You can create a Chrome extension that communicates with a native application on the user's machine via stdin/stdout.